# Let $N_1, . . . , N_n$ be normal subgroups of $G$, consider $G/N_1\times ··· \times G/N_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I’m reading Hans Kurzweil ‘s “The Theory of Finite Groups”, where it says

> 1.6.4 Let $N_1, . . . , N_n$ be normal subgroups of $G$. Then the mapping $$α: G→G/N_1\times ··· \times G/N_n$$  given by $$g \mapsto
> (gN_1,...,gN_n)$$ is a homomorphism with $\operatorname{Ker}α = \cap_i N_i$. In
>   particular, $G/\cap_i N_i$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/N_1
> \times ··· \times G/N_n$.

I’m confused here: can we write $$G/N_1\times \cdots \times G/N_n$$
? To write a product of groups as this, it’s required that each $G/N_i$ has only $e$ as common element.

What if $$G=C_2 \times C_3 \times C_5 \times C_7$$

$$N_1=C_2 \times C_3 $$

$$N_2=C_2 \times C_5 $$

$$N_3=C_2 \times C_7 $$

, shouldn’t $$G/N_1 \cong C_3 \times C_5$$

$$G/N_2 \cong C_2 \times C_7$$

$$G/N_3 \cong C_5 \times C_7$$

, and they have common elements besides $e$?

Comment: I believe this is the Chinese Reminder theorem for groups.

Comment: @IAmNoOne but there’s no solution formula?

Answer (score 3):

> I’m confused here: can we write $$G/N_1\times ··· \times G/N_n$$ ? To
>   write a product of groups as this, it’s required that each $G/N_i$ has
>   only $e$ as common element.

Note that $G/N_i$ is not a subgroup of  $G $. So here we are not considering the *internal direct product*, which requires the condition you mentioned above to be a group. Here $G/N_1\times ··· \times G/N_n$ represents the *external direct product* , which is a group under the componentwise operation.

Answer (score 0):

Given two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$, you can form their direct product:   $G_1×G_2$, to be $\{(g_1,g_2)\mid g_1\in G_1,g_2\in G_2\}$, with the group operation defined as $(g_1,g_2)+(h_1,h_2)=(g_1+h_1,g_2+h_2)$.

As an example,  consider the Klein four group, $V_4=C_2×C_2$.

(As in the other answer, you seem to be thinking of the internal direct product of subgroups of the given group.)